# Nvidia is loaded despite it being blacklisted

Tags: fedora, nvidia, bumblebee

I've got a problem: my laptop loads the Nvidia driver despite it having been added to `/etc/modprobe/blacklist.conf` as `blacklist nvidia`, as well as in `/etc/default/grub`, and as `rdblacklist nvidia` in `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX`. This leads to the machine running hot and not-so-smooth on battery.

Why is not Fedora not obeying my blacklist configuration? What can be done?

Update.

Files:

```
[0] % cat /etc/modprobe.d/bumblebee.conf       
blacklist nvidia
blacklist nouveau
options bbswitch load_state=0 unload_state=0

[0] % cat /etc/default/grub 
GRUB_TIMEOUT=5
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="$(sed 's, release .*$,,g' /etc/system-release)"
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
GRUB_DISABLE_SUBMENU=true
GRUB_TERMINAL_OUTPUT="console"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="rd.lvm.lv=fedora/root rd.lvm.lv=fedora/swap  nouveau.modeset=0 rd.driver.blacklist=nouveau,nvidia rhgb quiet"
GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"
```

EDIT: lsmod|grep nvidia

```
[1] % lsmod|grep nvidia
nvidia               8642560  1
drm                   335872  12 i915,drm_kms_helper,nvidia
```

Comment: Can you post the contents of all the relevant files, please?

Comment: yes, updating the post.

Comment: What module do you want to be loaded?

Comment: Hm? I want none. My graphic card I use daily is intel. My graphic card I use with bumblebee must not load either driver at boot.

Comment: I see. I'm not sure how to debug blacklisting. See https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=122062. In particular, this says (I haven't checked if it is true) "Using only blacklist let the module be loaded when it's needed by another module though." And suggests the syntax "install xxxx /bin/false".

Comment: Can you post the output of `lsmod | grep nvidia` please?

Comment: @ThomasZwaagstra, done. Can be seen that for some reason drm module depends on nvidia.

Comment: You might want to check your X11 configuration. If there's an card/device listed with the nvidia driver, it will get loaded despite being blacklisted. `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` and `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/*`

Comment: Nope, only configuration stuff for Xorg I have is synaptics configuration.

Comment: @MikhailKrutov Is the `drm` module being loaded, then?

Comment: @MikhailKrutov for completeness, update your initramfs with `dracut -f /boot/your-initramfs` so that it picks up your modprobe.d changes

Comment: @FaheemMitha, yes, drm module is being loaded, but I don't think it would be a wise move to blacklist it, since a VC I use (intel) still needs drm to function. Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Well, if the drm module is loaded, and the drm module depends on ndvidia, then the nvidia model will be loaded despite being blacklisted. That's your answer, I suppose, unless I'm missing something. Though I have no idea why the drm module requires nvidia to be loaded. You could possibly look into that.

Comment: @ThomasZwaagstra, I've done it again, and it fixed the issue to my surprise. Could you please convert it to the answer for me to accept it? I suppose the reason for it not to work in the 1st place was that may be I've updated the wrong initramfs on an old kernel.. or something in the lines.

Comment: Which video driver do you want to use for the text console? `vesafb`? AND: Tried to disable kernel mode setting via kernel boot parameter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The module might be loaded in the initramfs on boot. You must regenerate the initramfs to include your modifications to `/etc/modprobe.d/*`

Run the following to regenerate your initramfs

```
dracut -f /boot/your-initramfs
```

On reboot, the driver should not be loaded automatically

Comment: No problem. I haven't used bumblebee because my hardware doesn't support it, but I've had similar issues between nouveau/nvidia being loaded. Cheers

Answer (score -1):

If you need to blacklist something temporarily, or prefer to use Grub to do it for some reason, you can also edit your kernel boot options to blacklist the module as well:

```
vmlinuz ro rhgb quiet rdblacklist=<modulename>
```

This can be made permanent by adding it to /etc/default/grub on this line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="<existing boot options> rdblacklist=<modulename>"
```

And then updating your boot configuration with

```
grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
```

However this should usually be a last resort for blacklisting something.